# Is this a correct proof showing that the differential of the exponential map is the Identity at the origin?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ be the map going from the Lie Algebra to the Lie Group. I want to show that $d_0\exp = Id.$

Here is my attempt: First observe that if we set $\psi(t)=tX$ where $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ for $|t|<\epsilon$ then $\psi(0)=0$ and $\psi'(0)=X.$ Then I can write,
$$d_0\exp(X)=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}\exp(\psi(t)).$$
But I know that $\exp(tX)=\phi_X(t)$ where $\phi_X:\mathbb{R}\to G$ is the one parameter subgroup such that $\phi_X(0)=e$ and $\phi_X'(0)=X.$ Thus,
$$\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}\exp(\psi(t))=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}\phi_X(t)=\phi_X'(0)=X$$
and so $d_0\exp (X) =X.$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Looks right to me!